# iOS Project runs on simulator, physical device, but can't build or archive anymore for "iOS Device"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build, archive

To distribute test builds via TestFlight, I select "iOS Device" in the scheme, then click in the menu Product, Archive.  This all of a sudden stopped working with the error message:

[image]

When I try Product, Build, I get the same message.  I restarted my computer, auto-recreated the schemes, checked SDK settings and they look fine to me.  I loaded up a different project, and it archived fine.  Here are the product and target build settings (they are the same):

[image]

My only guess is that a file may have gotten corrupted, because I didn't manually change any of these settings.  Just editing code.

**EDIT:** After I wrote this question, I left my computer for 10 minutes.  Upon my return, I tried to build and archive just for the heck of it and it worked.  I don't know what to say...

**EDIT 2:** This is happening again and would like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: you have to use device or simulator only for build.

Comment: what did you see instead of "iOS Device"? Your physical device?

Comment: It happens to me all the time, someone maliciously messes up with my project settings too and fixes them after I leave ... darn those little kids of mine ;)

Comment: @SamBudda Those little kids must have returned :(

Answer (score 0):

After this happening a few times, I figured out the issue.  When my iPhone is hooked up to my Mac and tethering is on, this problem occurs.  When I turn tethering off, or disconnect the phone, I can archive again.  Not sure why this, but I hope it helps someone at some point.